# What is the best way to make SSIS calculate if a number is within an interval defined by two cells?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis

We have a 11 million record dataset, where two columns specify the start and end time of a shift. For our data warehouse we want a table that lists all shifts, but we also want 24 columns, one for each hour of the day.

If a shift has startTime = 15:00 and endTime = 19:00, I want column 15-18 populated with 1.
If a shift start at 15:30, column 15 should only contain 0,5.

11 million rows, and aritmetics on 24 columns for each row sounds expensive.

What is the best way to approach this using SSIS (and if necessary, stored procedures or functions)?

Comment: The result is gonna be stored in a database? You should do the calculations there then. For SQL Server, 11m rows shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I agree, SQL Server could easily pivot all 11M rows. I personally recommend using a "Cross Tab".

Comment: Hi, yes, the results are stored within the same database actually. So I can/should use SSIS for the ETL process and build the structure of the destination table, and then do the calculations within SQL server itself? Using for example a stored procedure and iterate over all rows and columns?

Comment: @swaglordmcmuffin' yes, you should load your table using SSIS then calculate all the derived data directly inside SQL Server with a script or SP. You won't have to "iterate", SQL is optimized to work with sets so you can do all your operations in batches effectively.

Comment: @EzLo Thank you for clarifying!